# How to merge selected List entries together in Scala? (i.e. produce a potentially shorter list)

Tags: scala

I have a list of text lines, and want to treat any lines ending with '\' as continuing to the next line, i.e. to merge them. The recursive code below does it, but there must be some clever way, similar to `map`, `filter` and all?

`reduceLeft` is close but it only produces a single result, not a modified (and potentially shorter) new list.

Also suggestions on making the code below leaner are welcome.

```
object TestX extends App {

  // Merge lines together if the former ends with '\'.
  //
  private def mergeLines( list: List[String] ): List[String] = {

    def merge( head: String, tail: List[String] ): List[String] = {
      if (head.endsWith("\\")) {
        val head2= head.dropRight(1)
        if (tail.isEmpty) {
          head2 :: Nil   // or throw an exception on bad input
        } else {
          merge( head2 + tail.head, tail.tail )
        }
      } else {
        if (tail.isEmpty)
          head :: Nil
        else 
          head :: merge( tail.head, tail.tail )     // note: cannot tailrec this
      }
    }

    if (list.isEmpty) {
      list
    } else {
      merge( list.head, list.tail )
    }
  }

  val list = "These two \\" :: "should be joined" :: "but not this." :: Nil

  val list2 = mergeLines(list)    // any standard easy way to do this? 'list.mergeIf( _.endsWith('\\') )'

  println( list2 )
  assert( list2.size == 2 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it using foldLeft:

```
List("a\\", "b", "c").foldLeft(List.empty[String])((xs, x) => xs match { 
  case Nil => x :: Nil
  case _ => if (xs.head.endsWith("\\")) (xs.head.dropRight(1) + x) :: xs.tail else x :: xs 
}).reverse
```

It's probably not the most efficient way (fine for small list, but not for huge) as it use an immutable data structure, a more efficient approach would use a mutable List.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tricks that you could use:

```
  @annotation.tailrec
  def mergeLines(xs: List[String], out: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = xs match {
    case Nil            => out.reverse
    case x :: Nil       => mergeLines(Nil, x :: out)
    case x :: y :: rest => 
      if (x endsWith """\""") mergeLines(x.init + y :: rest, out)
      else                    mergeLines(y :: rest, x :: out)
  }
```